# How do I fix this error in the algorithm header file?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos-high-sierra

I'm currently writing a code that receives a `string` as an input, checking whether or not it is comprised of only chars from the `car_acc` array and, if it isn't the case, requesting the input once again, using a do-while loop.

This is the code:

```
    char car_acc [11] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', ':'};
    deque <bool> contr_car;
    
    do
    {
        cout << "Inserire il tempo di attesa (ore:minuti:secondi) -> ";
        cin >> tempo; fflush (stdin);
        lung = (int) tempo.length ()-1;
        
        for (; i != lung; i+=1)
        {
            contr_car [i] = false;
        }
        
        for (i = 0; i != 11; i+=1)
        {
            if (car_acc [i] == tempo [j])
            {
                contr_car [j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while (all_of (contr_car [0], contr_car [lung], true) == false);
```

I'm using the `contr_car` deque to store whether or not each character in the `string` is equal to one of those stored in the `car_acc` array.

I'm receiving this error, linking in the `algorithm` header file:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:926:21: Indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
```

The error occurs in the part of the file that is defining the `all_of` function:

```
template <class _InputIterator, class _Predicate>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
bool
all_of(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Predicate __pred)
{
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        if (!__pred(*__first)) // error's here
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

I also get this message on the same line as the `while`:

```
In instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::all_of<bool, bool>' requested here
```

Using the `find ()` function in place of `all_of ()` doesn't fix the error.

I'm using a deque since I had to declare it outside of the loop, inside of which I get the size, so arrays weren't an option, and I don't really know how to use `vector <bool>`, since it works as a bitset.
I **did** include both the `algorithm` and `deque` headers.
I tried using a `vector <int>` but it still doesn't work, it only changes the message I get on the line where the `while` is at:

```
In instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::all_of<int, int>' requested here
```

I honestly have no clue how to fix it, since I'm just getting started with C++ and coding in general, so I would be really greatful if you could phrase your anwsers in a easy-to-understand way.

Comment: The error message is preceded by several lines of text that show the context of that error. In particular, one of them will point at a line in your source code, and that's the actual culprit; it's just that the compiler doesn't see anything wrong in that line until it gets down into the header, and then it tells you what problem the code in the header has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) is intended to invoke a unary predicate on every element within an iteration sequence, reaping either 'true' or 'false' from each, and answering with one encompassing 'true' (everything reported true) or 'false' (at least one thing reported false). To do this, you supply three things:

- A beginning iterator
- An ending iterator
- A callable unary predicate returning a bool.

Your code supplies exactly *none* of those, and therefore it is no wonder it won't compile. An example of how you can use `std::all_of` is shown below. It isn't intended to be cookie-cutter, so *please* don't think otherwise.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::unordered_set<char> car_acc = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', ':'};
    std::string tempo;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Inserire il tempo di attesa (ore:minuti:secondi) -> ";
        std::cout.flush();

        if (!(std::cin >> tempo))
        {
            // TODO: handle failure on stdin
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

    } while ( !std::all_of(tempo.begin(), tempo.end(), 
        [&car_acc](char c){return car_acc.find(c) != car_acc.end();}) );

    std::cout << "You entered: " << tempo << '\n';
}
```

This simply creates an unordered set containing what you've deemed are "allowable" characters, then uses that set as the basis for the unary predicate here, a simple lambda:

```
[&car_acc](char c){return car_acc.find(c) != car_acc.end();}
```

This is then fed through `std::all_of` using the string begin and end iterators. If any character in the string fails to find a match in the set, the result of that match-check will be false, and therefore shall also be the result of `std::all_of`.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work just fine. Going to test this later, but it does compile, which is definitely an improvement.

Comment: @LSD_Sumus initially I thought you were not only shooting for "only these are allowed" but also "all of these are required", which is a considerably different, more complex solution. Hopefully the former was the goal and not the latter.

Comment: No, tested it, it does do exactly what I needed it too, thank you